# Adding more fields to the registration process

Tags: 7, users

In Drupal 7, is there a way to add more fields to the registration process? I was thinking along the lines of birthday, fullname, gender, twitter, etc. Also how do I access this data once it's in, so I can output it to my template files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since D7, field management is included in the core. Almost every kind of content has now the ability to be managed with fields.

You can go to admin/config/people/accounts/fields to manage user fields. There is also a tab for managing the display.

Comment: Where is this *admin/config/people/accounts/fields?* I can't find it in D7.

Comment: You need to go to :
Configuration > People (first block in default admin) > Account settings. In the account settings page there is a "Manage Fields" tab.

Comment: I'm able to add new fileds, but cannot make them visible on the registration process!

Comment: @Dewsworld you need to check mark at 'Display on user registration form.' at the field edit page, e.g for Date of birth field(field_dob) the url is admin/config/people/accounts/fields/field_dob.

Comment: I have been able to do all of the above, but my fields don't show up on the edit account pages for the users, only for the admin. Any ideas? I would be very grateful!

Comment: @reptilex, I found the problem that caused this issue for me, it was that I had the Organic Group Field Access module enabled.  Once I disabled it, everything works again for my users.  More details at: https://www.drupal.org/node/1201582

Answer (score 0):

Administration » Configuration » People » Account settings » Manage fields

Make sure once again by edit the new fields and its check box for  Required field and 
Display on user registration form will be enabled.