# multiple (two at least) user registration forms

Tags: users

I have built a registration form with a few custom fields, works fine. Now I need to another registration form, but with a dozen or so more fields. Both need to force drupal into its user registration/validation process.

it has to be done this way, I cannot just redirect a user to register first then fill out a survey.

Alex

Comment: So what's your question?  What's not working for you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding more fields to the registration process](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5478/adding-more-fields-to-the-registration-process)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using [Profile 2](https://drupal.org/project/profile2) and [Profile2 Registration Path](https://drupal.org/project/profile2_regpath) module.

**Profile 2**

> Multiple profile types may be created via the UI (e.g. a general
>   profile + a customer profile), whereas the module provides separated
>   permissions for those

**Profile2 Registration Path**

> This module enables administrators to set unique registration paths
>   per Profile2 profile type

Comment: I eventually found that module(s) but I am still not clear on whether that solves this specific problem.

There are no two profiles, just one, a member sign ups. The caveat being, if they click one link to sign up, they get the standard details collection. If they should click the other link, they get the same form but with a dozen "survey" type fields.

This process is a little confusing, but this is what the boss has requested.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

if you want to add data to the user, add fields here (admin/config/people/accounts). see [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5478/adding-more-fields-to-the-registration-process)

[webform](https://drupal.org/project/Webform) is a very nice module, where you can create forms via the UI, also offers stats etc.

Comment: We cant include webform in profile fields.

Comment: Can't use webform, that is what I am using now, until it was requested that a user be able to sign up and/or signup and fill out a survey all in the same form/page. I tried negotiating a registration first and redirect to survey but that doesn't work for her I guess.